# Can't write new XML file on web folder (Godaddy using plesk for windows)

Tags: asp.net, xml, file-permissions, web-hosting

I have an asp.net website that create some xml files on the fly. I succeed to run this on my pc. but when I upload the project to the hosting (Godaddy) the file xml files can't be created. I already fixed the permission to the destination folder, but nothing change. still can't create the xml files.

Are there any solutions to my problem ? thanks

Comment: what error you got.?

Comment: the error show after my web try to read the xml file. the file is not in the folder or had not been created.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is trust level.GoDaddy's trust level medium.Thus you can not create xml file due to security reasons.You should find another hosting company which allow full trust level.

Comment: Changing to another hosting is not the best solution right now.